# Suggestion for interactive mapping solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for a mapping solution for my department.  We have servers set up at multiple locations within the continental U.S.  At each of these sites, is multiple servers, that handle multiple data types.  The overall goal of this map is to be able to select and/or filter, to help my team and I keep track of our assets.

So we have sites at locations like Orlando and San Francisco.  At each of these sites, is a few data types.  I would like the map to be clickable for one...be able to select a site.  When I select a site, it should show me all of the servers in the correct setup, and the data flowing through them.  I should also have a legend that shows the data types and corresponding color for it.  The color would be for the line that is drawn across the map that shows the data flowing from site to site, and then from server to server.  So on the legend, I should be able to select a data type, and have it show or highlight just that data flow, so I can track it easier.  Of course labels and other interactivity would be terrific as well.

Does anyone have a legitimate solution for this, preferably something free or cheap?  Hopefully something manageable for a novice.  I was looking at possibly a jQuery solution using jVector maps.  I was not sure if this had all of the potential I was looking for.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using jVectorMap. It may be that for certain additional features you need some coding of your own (like I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ28/117/): `links with jVectorMap`), but it's pretty easy to use.

You can also check out [jqvmap](http://jqvmap.com/) and [mapael](http://www.neveldo.fr/mapael/).

For a paid solution, take a look at [jQueryMaps](http://www.jquerymaps.com/).